# How are Top Askers in a filter listed?

Tags: support, tag-filters

I'm using [SE filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters). In the sidebar, there is a list with "Top Askers":

> **Top Askers**
>
> *These users asked the most up-voted questions on this page*

But to me, it looks more like a list of the *most recent* askers. So how does it work, exactly?